# How to filter IQueryable dynamically by generic field

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to make a IDictionary<TKey, List<TSource>> class where I can decide the key by a func. I have managed to build the class with arrays like this (functions are simplified for examples sake):

```
private List<TSource> Filter(TKey key, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    IQueryable<TSource> source = GetSource(); // It's there
    IQueryable<TSource> filtered = source.Where(
        x => keySelector.Invoke(x).Equals(key)
        );
    return filtered.ToList();
}
```

But this works only with arrays and such, not with linq-to-sql. I understand this can be done with expressions, but thats mostly beyond me. I have googled and come up with the following functions:

```
private List<TSource> Filter(TKey key, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    IQueryable<TSource> source = GetSource();
    Func<TSource, bool> compiledKeyFilter = GetFilter(keySelector);
    IEnumerable<TSource> filtered = source.Where(compiledKeyFilter);
    return filtered.ToList();
}
private Func<TSource, bool> GetFilter(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> expr)
{
    if (this.filter == null)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr, expr.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        var lamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
            Expression.Call(expr.Body, typeof(TKey).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(TKey) }), invokedExpr),
            expr.Parameters
            );
        this.filter = lamda.Compile();
    }

    return this.filter;
}
```

This currently returns all rows in the source. The expression should be reusable, not just for one-time execution. I found the following from SO ([Dynamically generated lookup key for IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640229/dynamically-generated-lookup-key-for-iqueryable)), what I'm doing is quie similar. It works, but I'm unable to combine it with the compiled approach:

```
private Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> MakeFilterExpression(TKey key)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Invoke(keySelector, param),
                Expression.Constant(key)
            ),
        param
        );
}
```

So I'm trying to come up with a class that I could use like this:

```
// Inside MyCache there would be something close to this:
class MyCache
{
    private Func<TSource, bool> filter;
    public MyCache(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> func)
    {
        this.filter = MakeFilter(func);
    }
    private Func<TSource, bool> MakeFilter(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> func)
    {
        // magic
    }
    public List<TSource> GetByKey(TKey key)
    {
        return GetSource().Where(this.filter(key)).ToList();
    }
}

// This is my class where I give my func to determine the key in ctor.
var cache = new MyCache<MySource>(x => x.myField);
var list1 = cache.GetByKey(3); // Now I have list to iterate.
var list2 = cache.GetByKey(4); // Here's another list.
```

Is it even possible to compile that into a reusable function? Help?!

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve. Give examples of: 1) Your source data; 2) Your desired result; 3) Your actual result.

Comment: Are you trying to come up with a version of the `Filter` that works with LINQ-to-SQL queries given the `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` key selector?

Comment: I added a use case, hope it clarifies.

Comment: Why do you want to convert an expression to a function (a delegate)? LINQ-to-SQL does not understand delegates, it understands only  expressions because it needs to translate them to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you are trying to come up with a version of the `Filter` method that works with LINQ-to-SQL queries given an `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` key selector.

You can use the [LINQKit library](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to help you with that. It allows you to invoke one expression from another one and then "expand" the result expression.

Here is how you would code your `Filter` method with the help of LINQKit:

```
private static List<TSource> Filter<TSource,TKey>(
    TKey key,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    IQueryable<TSource> source = GetSource<TSource>(); // It's there

    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate = x => keySelector.Invoke(x).Equals(key);

    //LINQ-to-SQL cannot translate `Invoke` into SQL. However, after invoking this line
    //LINQKit would flatten the expression so that it contains something like
    //x => x.Age.Equals(5) (for a keySelector of value x => x.Age and key of value 5)
    predicate = predicate.Expand();

    IQueryable<TSource> filtered = source.Where(predicate);

    return filtered.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi, this comes close, but as Filter can be called many times, I would prefer a way where the whole predicate doesn't always need to be created from ground up.

Comment: Building the expression should be really fast. Try to measure how much it takes to build a 1000 expression this way to estimate how much building one would take and see if it is significant

Comment: It's not as fast as I would like, but it's fast enough. I'll mark this as an answer for pointing out LinqKit functions and explaining about linq-to-sql and expressions.